# No aparece la interfaz gráfica para el desarrollo de aplicaciones en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy iniciandome en android y es la primera vez que trabajo con **Android Studio** y tengo el siguiente problema:

**Problema:** *La interfaz gráfica para desarrollar aplicaciones android no me aparece*

**Captura de Pantalla del Problema**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le he estado moviendo a a Android Studio, pero desconozco que es lo que causa el problmea.

Comment: En la parte inferior te aparece una actualización, has intentado actualizar tu programa ?

Comment: De hecho antes que apareciera eso, me decía que instalara apis y otras herramientas del sdk, pero aunque las he instalado no funciona.

Comment: @FernyCortez te pido por favor vayas a Tools > Settings > Appareance & Behaviour > System Settings > Android SDK y agregues una imagen de la configuración.

Comment: Me puedes decir que fue lo que descargaste Tengo el mismo problema

Comment: @Salvador Cuandos estas instalando te van a apareciendo las cosas que tienes que instalar, eso fue lo que yo hice, realmente no recuerdo en lo particular que cosas fueron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No aparece la UI de tu layout debido a que tu proyecto no pudo ser construido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay dos razones importantes de esto, debes instalar el SDK Android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y las Platform Tools

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debes asegurar tener configurado el Android SDK, ve a

`Tools` > `Settings` > `Appareance & Behaviour` > `System Settings` > `Android SDK`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Teniendo configurado el SDK y definiendo la ruta correcta, Android Studio mostrará opciones para instalar los demás componentes.**

Comment: Todo eso lo tengo, voy a instalar el `plataform tools`, espero y sea eso

Comment: En tu imagen se muestra que no tienes platform tools o alguna Api

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, era instalar varias cosas. Pero me sirvió y ya puedo visualizar la `UI`

Comment: @FernyCortez excelente Ferny! Saludos!